# Swift generics in protocols

Tags: ios, swift, macos, generics

What is an appropriate way to solve the following example with swift?

I know because of type erasure that you cannot assign `StructB` to `item2` in the constructor. In other languages like *Java* I would solve the problem by not having a generic class parameter `T` in the `Container` struct but let vars `item` and `item2` just be the type of `ProtocolA` (like `var item2: ProtocolA`).
This is not allowed by swift: *Protocol 'ProtocolA' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements*

I worked through [this](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) section of swifts documentation about generics but so far I was not able to adapt a solution for my simple problem:

```swift
protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype B
    
    func foo() -> B
}


struct StructA: ProtocolA {
    typealias B = String
    
    func foo() -> String {
        "Hello"
    }
}

struct StructB: ProtocolA {
    typealias B = Double
    
    func foo() -> Double {
        0.0
    }
}

struct Container<T: ProtocolA> {
    
    var item: T
    var item2: T
    
    init(item: T) {
        self.item = item
        self.item2 = StructB() // err: Cannot assign value of type 'StructB' to type 'T'
    }
}
```

I also want to know how a solution could look if I do not want to specify a generic type parameter at all for the container struct. So that I could write the following:

```swift
func test() {
    let container = Container(StructA()) // no type given
}
```

Comment: If Item2 will be other thing that protocol type you use to create Container then it cannot be type B : for ex : if you choose T is StructA, Item2 will be structA = something working with string .it can not manage double. If you know which type is Item2, declare it as StrucB. Item.foo will return String and item2.foo will return double. If you want to have 2 different type you must use 2 associated types

Comment: "I know because of type erasure that you cannot assign StructB to item2 in the constructor" That's not it. Swift's generics aren't erased at runtime like Java's. The particular issue here is that `T` refers to *one specific type* (which must conform to `ProtocolA`). You can't assign `StructB` where `T` is expected, because that would only ever work when `T` is exactly `StructA`. That is, it would completely defeat the point of generics. Recommendation a solution is hard without more context on the real problem, though.

Comment: "Recommendation a solution is hard without more context on the real problem" I want to have a Container with two variables of type ProtocolA

Comment: I think this is a bug: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0309-unlock-existential-types-for-all-protocols.md

Comment: how do you want to init your 2 variables ?

Comment: @PtitXav that may depend on the other conditions. So I do not know if StructA or StructB will be the "specific type". Maybe it is an entirely different struct or class. It should not matter as long as it implements ProtocolA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem as described, the answer is very straightforward:

```
struct Container<T: ProtocolA> {

    var item: T
    var item2: StructB // This isn't T; you hard-coded it to StructB in init

    init(item: T) {
        self.item = item
        self.item2 = StructB()
    }
}

let container = Container(item: StructA()) // works as described
```

I get the feeling that there's something deeper to this question, which is why Alexander was asking for more context. As written, the question's answer seems too simple, so some of us assume that there's more that you didn't explain, and we want to avoid a round of "here's the answer" followed by "that's not what I meant."

As you wrote it, you try to force `item` and `item2` to have the same type. That's obviously not what you mean because `T` is given by the caller, and `item2` is always StructB (which does not have to equal `T`, as the error explains).

Is there another way you intend to call this code? It's unclear what code that calls `foo()` would look like. Do you have some other way you intend to initialize Container that you didn't explain in your question?

Maybe you want two different types, and you just want StructB to be the default? In that case, it would look like (based on Ptit Xav's answer):

```
struct Container<T: ProtocolA, U: ProtocolA> {

    var item: T
    var item2: U

    // Regular init where the caller decides T and U
    init(item: T, item2: U) {
        self.item = item
        self.item2 = item2
    }

    // Convenience where the caller just decides T and U is default
    init(item: T) where U == StructB {
       self.init(item: item, item2: StructB())
    }
}
```

The `where U == StructB` allows you to make a default type for U.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the problem by your answer. The hint with the second constructor and the „where U == Struct B“ is a good solution I did not know so far. I think I was wrong in interpreting the T: ProtocolA as „anything of type T“ and not as „only exactly type T“

Comment: But regarding to https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0309-unlock-existential-types-for-all-protocols.md I think my question can be reduced to "how to use a protocol with associated types as a type" and that is not possible in the latest version of swift

Comment: Fixed with Swift 5.6: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/247/whats-new-in-swift-5-6

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do something like you want is :

```
struct Container<T: ProtocolA,U: ProtocolA> {

    var item: T
    var item2: U

    init(item: T, item2: U) {
        self.item = item
        self.item2 = item2
    }
}
```